# Is there a CSS postprocessor to inject browser prefixes in CSS files at build time?

Tags: css, sbt, playframework-2.3

Is there a css postprocessor for the Play Framework 2.3.x that automatically adds browser prefixes to a CSS file's rule set?

For example if I'm using Flexbox and my CSS file has this following:

```
a {  
    display: flex 
}
```

After a build I'd like that CSS rule to be transformed to:

```
a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex
}
```

So it'd support all the browser specific prefixes without me having to look them up.

I found a javascript solution called [prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) but I'd prefer a server side solution (preferable when the css and other assets get compiled together).

Comment: What text do you use?..

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. For text encoding, I presume the CSS file will be UTF-8. If you're asking about my IDE, I use Eclipse although that should not matter since I'm looking for a SBT (Play Framework's build tool) plugin not a Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Have you used a plugin like "Emmet"? it allows you to easily add vendor prefixes.

Comment: The Emmet Eclipse Plugin is handy but it implements vendor prefixes in a somewhat dumb manner. Inside your CSS rule if you type `-float` and then press tab it'll blindly create the `-ms, -webkit, -moz, -o` even though it's not needed for the float attribute. It definitely is better than nothing though. More information for those that are curious about Emmet: http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/vendor-prefixes/ .

Comment: Why not just use a preprocessor like Sass or Less? That way you won't run into any overhead issues that would slow response times. The reason why something like what you are describing is hard to find is because CSS isn't a programming language. There are no variables that have to be calculated at runtime or when the page is being loaded. CSS is static. Preprocessors simply compile to static CSS.